# versão ado.net do iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, iis, wmi

Boas,

tenho o seguinte código:

```
    private void AspNet35()
    {
        String sWebSite = "W3SVC/1";

        DirectoryEntry site = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/" + sWebSite + @"/Root");
        try
        {
            PropertyValueCollection vals = site.Properties["ScriptMaps"];
            foreach (string val in vals)
            {
                if (val.StartsWith(".aspx"))
                {
                    string version = val.Substring(val.IndexOf("Framework") + 10, 9);

                    if (version == "3.5") 
                    { 
                        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("ASP.Net Version on virtual server is {0}", version));
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        catch
        {

        } 
    }
```

A ideia era verificar se o IIS tem o asp.net 3.5 instalado. Ou pelo menos verificar quis as versões instaladas.

Como consigo fazer isso?

Obrigado

Comment: Você não fez nenhuma pergunta

Comment: A pergunta era como sei se o asp.net 3.5 está instalado usando c#? tentei com o código acima mas não funcionou.

Comment: Retirei o -1 agora que a questão está clara

Answer (score 0):

Essa página da Microsoft contém diversos meios de verificar a versão do .Net Framework:

[Como determinar quais versões do .NET Framework estão instaladas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#clr_b)

Para a versão 4.0 ou posteriores do .Net Framework ela sugere usar Environment.Version, mas as versões anteriores não tem essa propriedade, por isso ela sugere o verificar a versão usando o Registro do Windows, só que o usuário padrão do Application Pool do ASP.Net não tem acesso ao registro, então será necessário configurar um usuário diferente no App Pool do ASP.Net no servidor web, para que isso funcione.